# prevent search button from clearing search bar text

Tags: iphone, objective-c

After clicking "search" on the keyboard, the search bar text clears.  Is there a way to keep the text in the search bar? Why would it disappear?

Note:  I'm using the search display controller to activate and deactive the search

Comment: i looked at other apps where they use the search display controller.  looks like it is standard for the search text to disappear. clicking the search button shouldn't deactivate the search bar, instead it should just hide the keyboard. thx for your help

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. I am also using a search display controller` and the search bar text does not clear when I tap "Search". I have done nothing special to prevent it. Can you post some code related to this? Maybe your `SearchDisplayControllerDelegate` and `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol implementation?

Comment: make sure you are not altering searchBar.text in searchButtonClicked delegate (if you are using one).

Answer (score 1):

I found this from a somewhat related question... but the following code should keep the search term visible when the user clicks the search button.

```
-(void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSString *str = searchBar.text;
    [self.searchController setActive:NO animated:YES];
    self.searchController.searchBar.text = str;
}
```

Comment: I'd wrap it with retain and release. The setActive:animated: method may render the str pointer invalid by internally releasing it. By increasing retain counter ourselves we can make sure it's still available.